# Sylow subgroup of group$G= S4 *S3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have  stuck with the problem
How to find 2sylow and 3sylow subgroup of$ S3*S4$
if someone can help
thanks in advance

Comment: * means free product or??

Comment: This is why the notation is ambiguous. If free product was really intended, then all $2$-subgroups of the free product are finite, but there is more than one conjugacy class of maximal $2$-subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: You should explain what you mean by your notation. It could be ambiguous. I assume you mean the direct product of $S_{3}$ and $S_{4}$ in this case.
 If general, suppose that finite groups $G$ and $H$ have respective Sylow $p$-subgroups
$P$ and $Q$. Then $P \times Q$ is a subgroup of $G \times H.$ What can you say about $[G \times H: P \times Q]$?

Comment: I could not understand

Comment: Are you familiar with the notation for the index of a subgroup?

Comment: @ansari: Note that when $|G|=m, |H|=n$ then $|G\times H|=mn$ and when $|G|, |K|\le\infty$ where $K\le G$ then $[G:K]=|G|/|K|$.